# how to use node-webkit with express server?

Tags: node.js, express, node-webkit

I am developing an app using nodejs and express.
I want to export it as a package with node-webkit.
How can I start server and run app with it ?

Comment: I answered the question curious if it helped

Answer (score 1):

I am working on learning this myself. Here are the basics for converting an express app to a node webkit app.

I will assume that you have a node.js app with two modules installed. The first being express.js and the second some template engine. I am using handlebars so I will use it for this example.

I will also assume the app you want to convert is the simplest one possible, in short I will assume you are using express to do two things - run a server and respond to a single route that renders a view file

**Step 1.**

Download node webkit:  http://nwjs.io/

**Step 2.**

Unzip it

**Step 3.**

Open up the console and cd into the newly created folder (I will call this directory **app-parent** from here on out). Once you are there -  run this command:

```
npm install express
```

When this is done run:

```
npm install express-handlebars
```

**Step 4:**

In **app-parent** create two additional folders. One named **resources** and the other named **views**. Also in **app-parent** create a file called **package.json**.

Copy the following code into **package.json**

```
{
    "name": "app",
    "main": "resources/index.html"
}
```

**Step 5:**

Go to the resources folder and create a file named **index.html**. Inside of this copy the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>

</head>
<!--______________________________________________________BEGIN APP-->

<body>
    <script>
    </script>
    <script>
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();

    var expressHbs = require('express-handlebars');

    app.engine('hbs', expressHbs({
        extname: 'hbs'
    }));

    app.set('view engine', 'hbs');


    app.get("/", function(req, res) {
        res.render("index", {
            item: "weeeeeeeee"
        })
    })



    app.listen("3000", function(err) {

        if (err) {
            console.log("server is not working");
        } else {
            console.log("Server is working on 3000");
        }
    })



    window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000';
    </script>
</body>
<!--______________________________________________________END APP-->

</html>
```

**Step 7.**

Go to the views folder in **app-parent** and create a new file called **index.hbs**. Inside this file copy the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>

    </head>
    <!--______________________________________________________BEGIN APP-->
    <body>
        <p>Oink</p>
        {{item}}
    </body>
    <!--______________________________________________________END APP-->
</html>
```

**Final step.**

Inside **app-parent** click the file named **nw.exe**. Your app should launch.

**DONE**

Comment: how to include express and express handle in the nwjs installation for easy package for end users?

Answer (score -3):

Node-Webkit(means nodeJS+chromium framework) so you can run your server code(Express.js,etc) directly to your app(just install expressJS and then call directly client side  code) that's it

Comment: Care to elaborate that with more details?